# Keep everything after the first occurence of a specified character in R

Tags: r, string

Im using rvest to extract data from a webiste. The results are things like

`[1] <div>Pflichtbereich<br>    - Allgemeiner Bereich</div>
[2] <div>Pflichtbereich<br>    - Berufsfachlicher Bereich</div>
[3] <div>Wahlpflichtbereich</div>
[4] <div>Wahlbereich</div>`

I want to keep everything that is a regular "word". I started by removing `<div>` etc. with gsub. But sometimes the expression is `<br>` or `<i>` or something like that. To make things easier, I want to

1. remove everything before the first appearance of > (including the ">" )

   `<div>Wahlbereich</div> becomes Wahlbereich</div>`
2. remove everything after the first appearance of < (including the "<" )

`Wahlbereich</div> becomes Wahlbereich`

I tried several things with regexpressions, but I am not able to find the right combination yet.

```
sub(".*\\>","", <div>Wahlbereich</div>) gives me "<"
```

I think it has something to do with the fact that the "<" appears multiple times. I dont know how to "find the first appearance".

Best regards

Comment: Since you're already using `rvest`, do not David Robinson's answer at the dupe, not just the top answer.

Comment: Use the `html_text()` function from the rvest package.